# How to retrieve multiple aggregate columns from SQL Server in a SQL View/Access Query (pref SQL View)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table `tblRecords`, into this table are inserted 3500 records each day.  `tblRecords` has a foreign key linking it to `tblUpload`.  Each Row is identified, apart from a generic `ID` column, by a `REF` (ie: XYDG74G) and the Foreign Key Column (ie: 345) that links it to `tblUpload`.

The circa 3500 rows that are uploaded each day are the same rows as were uploaded from the previous day (with updates) as well as additional, new entries from the last 24 hrs.

Each `tblRecord` row can be flagged (BIT column) as `MissCustName` and `MissCustNameFixed`.  I view the `tblRecord` rows by `tblUpload`, that is to say I “Show me all (3500+) records uploaded today”.  I want, along with the actual columns in `tblRecord` to see two columns, `CountOfPrevMissCustName` and `CountOfPrevMissCustNameFixed`

```
ID - Ref - CustName - CountofPrevMissCustName- CountofPrevMissCustNameOK

1 - AASD001 - <NULL> - 14 - 12

2 - ZRFG789 - Joe Bloggs - 10 - 8

3 - YERF777 - Mary Blyge - 0 - 0
```

Missing Customer Name counts the total records (historical) for that Transaction where Missing Customer Name is flagged as TRUE. `MissNameFixed does the same.

1. Record 1 has previously had 14 missing customer name flags and 12 MissNameCustNameOK flags, but is still missing the customer name.
2. Record 2 has previously had 10 missing customer name flags, and 8 MissNameCustNameOK flags and currently has a customer name.
3. Record 3 has never had any missing customer name flags and hence no MissNameCustNameOK flags and currently has a name.

What would be the most efficient (quickest and less stress on SQL Server) to implement these 'dcount' style columns. Trying a dcount column within Access is painfully slow 9See below), as is using DAO recordsets in Access.

`SELECT *, dcount("RecordID","tblRecordsHistorical","Ref=" & Ref & " AND CustName is null) as CountofPrevMissCustName, dcount("RecordID","tblRecordsHistorical","Ref=" & Ref & " AND CustName is not null) as CountofPrevMissCustNameOK from tblRecords`

I would ideally like to be able to create some kind of view, that I could load, then use to do a bulk update on the table.

I will only ever work on the latest batch of tblRecords so once the CountOf... physical columns have been updated once, they don't need to be again.

Thnx

Comment: Are you asking just about sql server? Your question title suggests you are asking about both. Each could likely be different.

Comment: @Andrew Barber - Apologies, looking for a Server side solution as I presume it will be more efficient.

Comment: You could be presuming wrong. Where is your data stored and why do you need DCount? What is the sql of your query and have you any sample data?

Comment: Currently there are 50 sets of 3500 records in the table.  The fields that I need to count are boolean. I need to count the boolean fields in historical entries in order ot prioritise workload.

Comment: There is a big difference between count and dcount. 3,500 is not a large set of records. Even with SQL Server, the speed will depend on how you have set up your query and how you have indexed you tables. You should post sample data and the sql you are using.

Comment: I've heavily rewritten the description, hopefully what I am looking for is more understandable now.

Comment: I really do not understand why it is not possible for you to post sample data and your current sql. Sample data and sql are far more descriptive than any number of words for most people here.

Comment: The sample data has been there all along, I've posted the query I currently use within access that has two aggregate fields, which I would prefer was on the server somehow.  The other alternative (if possible) is to place a SELECT COUNT(*) inside a trigger?!??!